# In octave, what are the error tolerance options in numerical integration?

Tags: matlab, octave, numerical-integration

In Octave, you can call quad_options to get:

```
quad_options()

Options for Quad include:

keyword                                             value
-------                                             -----
absolute tolerance                                  1.49012e-08
relative tolerance                                  1.49012e-08
single precision absolute tolerance                 0.000345267
single precision relative tolerance                 0.000345267
```

Can someone explain the difference between these four kinds of error tolerances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the difference between absolute and relative tolerance see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961844/relative-and-absolute-tolerance-definitions-in-matlab-solver). The last two are the same but when you are using data with [single precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) instead of [double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).