# how to change the values of convergence in optim in r

Tags: r, optimization

I am working with big and complex function. I am using `optim` to estimate the model parameters. I see from the iteration values of `optim`, it does not converge even if the current and last values are very close.

For example,

```
iteration 10  400.0091
iteration 20  400.0092
iteration 30  400.0093
  :
  :
```

keep going, say for  iteration 1200.

So how can I change the convergence round of the `optim` that is, if the current iteration is very close to previous iteration then converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `abstol` or `reltol` which are components `control` argument.

See `?optim` for more details. I can't recommend one without an example/context for your question but your call will look something like:

```
optim(par, fn, [other vars?], control = list(reltol = 1e-5))
```

Comment: what are the absolute and relative tolerances exactly doing?

Comment: already found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961844/relative-and-absolute-tolerance-definitions-in-matlab-solver